# Failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:3000] when running Meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to run a newly created Meteor app on Windows 10 with:

```
meteor create foo
cd foo
meteor
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:3001]
    at Object.Future.wait (C:\Users\Pechi\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15)
    at Object.exports.waitForOne (C:\tools\utils\fiber-helpers.js:52:25)
    at yieldingMethod (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:376:25)
    at initiateReplSetAndWaitForReady (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:546:7)
    at launchMongo (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:658:9)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:756:19)
    at [object Object]._.extend.start (C:\tools\runners\run-mongo.js:714:10)
    at C:\tools\runners\run-all.js:168:26
    - - - - -
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pechi\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\mongo\npm\npm-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:556:74)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:106:17)
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pechi\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\mongo\npm\npm-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:156:15)
    at [object Object].emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pechi\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.10\mt-os.windows.x86_32\isopackets\mongo\npm\npm-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection.js:534:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

Meteor Version is 1.2.1. Firewall and AntiVir Apps are turned off.
Several deinstallations and new installations doesn't work either

Comment: try different port `meteor run --port 3030`. Did you get the same error?

Comment: Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:3001] - 3001 is mongoDB port. Did you install mongo?

Comment: With `meteor run --port xxxxx` I'm getting the same error.
I didn't install mongoDB separatley, because Meteor is shipped with a MongoDB installation.

Comment: Does that happen with an example app or with your own code?

Comment: I've just created a new app with `meteor create foo`

Comment: which windows do you use?

Comment: Windows 10 Education